# Реализация взаимодействий 3D объектов в 4D пространстве в Unity

Tags: unity3d, объекты, 3d

Появилась идея по реализация Хогвартса из фанфика "Гарри Поттер и Методы Рационального Мышления". Явно об этом не упоминается, но по описанию возможности наложения пространства и отсутствия видимого различия в направлении и длине между проходами ведущими в разные места, можно понять, что Хогвартс находится в псевдо-4D пространстве, созданным с помощью магии. Но я наткнулся на проблему: я не знаю, как в Unity сделать взаимодействие между 3D объектами, но в 4D пространстве.
На рисунке изображены 2D персонажи в псевдо 3D пространстве (Это просто несколько уровней 2D), когда они идут в один из проходов они не замечают изменения высоты так, как они видят в 2D. Если один из персонажей посмотрит с высоты 0.5 на высоту 1 или 0, то он увидит то, что там находится, ведь разница недостаточная, но если смотреть с высоты 0 на высоту 1, то нельзя будет увидеть, что там (слишком высоко). Тоже самое происходит в псевдо-4D пространстве Хогвартса, но только коридоры меняют не высоту, а координату w, а так, как мы 3D существа, то мы не увидим этого изменения. [image: 2d characters in 3d space]

Высота на рисунке может меняться от 0 до одного, это отображается цветом от черного до белого.

Comment: К сожалению метка 4D отсутствует

Comment: Можете посмотреть 4д игры сделанные на юнити. https://youtube.com/watch?v=0t4aKJuKP0Q     https://youtube.com/watch?v=9yW--eQaA2I  Больше не знаю чем помочь)

Comment: Спасибо, но к сожалению я уже видел эти ролики. Мне нужно именно взаимодействие 3d объектов в 4d, а судя по всему авторы данных игр не собираются бесплатно делиться своими наработками, особенно учитывая, что даже сами игры платные.